# MVC set Data annotations attributes in code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is it possible to set range (or any other model `DataAnnotations` attributes) in code and keep all the `DataAnnotations` behaviour?

i.e. I have a decimal model that I want to set its minimum value in code (on page load for example) in a way I could keep using the `ValidationMessageFor` ?

my current "static" model

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Price")]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid price format")]
public decimal MinimumPrice { get; set; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, DataAnnotations are compiled into the code at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime.

If you insist on using DataAnnotations, then there really is no other choice.

If you are willing to do something else, then you have a number of other options.  You could create your own Attribute that would read values from the variable of your choice (though you can't pass a variable to it).

Or you could use FluentValidation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve some of what you want using Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
        .Property(x => x.MinimumPrice )
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("decimal")
            .HasPrecision(18, 2);     
            // default vals for decimal type. 18 = precision = how many digits in 
            // total. 2 = scale = digits after decimal                   
}
```

For some things it's better to use fluent configuration and others to use annotations.

[Further reading](http://dotnetdevdude.com/Blog/CommentView,guid,13539030-3de2-4021-a125-0c446f6b4283.aspx).

Comment: That changes the database, not the view model.